# Blank Safari Tabs

Tags: safari, tabs

All of the tabs on Safari are blank.  I have tried settings, closing and re-opening, re-booting the computer, etc. I can no longer use Safari because it's too difficult without being able to see what's open.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/343745/edit) your question and specify the version of macOS and Safari running on your Mac. It may also help to know the make and model of your Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Try this from [this apple support discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8281803)

> 1. Click the apple logo in the menu bar and choose “Force Quit”.
>
> In the window that opens up, select “Safari” and click “Force Quit".
>
> 2. Relaunch Safari holding the shift key down.